# InstallShield is not able to Copy to ProgramData

Tags: installation, installshield, setup-deployment

I have a problem with InstallShield that grinds my gears. I'm not an expert, but I'm using IS for over three years now. Here is the szenario:

My program installs a config file under *C:\ProgramData\[CompanyName]\[Product Name]\*. When I install an update it should rename the old *.cfg* file to an *.bak* file so that we can update the *.cfg* file too. But for no apparent reason this doesn't work anymore. It worked for years with the old IS2012, but now it has stopped working. I tried it with an InstallScript, with the MoveFile Table and other methods. Nothing worked.

But when I try to rename (and copy) the file to the installation folder (under *ProgramFiles*) it is working. But it's working nowhere else.

Has someone an idea why I am now unable to write into this folder? I am very disappointed and have no more ideas...

Thanks for help, and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Can you be add more details about how you are attempting to copy the file, and find out what a verbose windows installer log says about it (if anything), and/or what process monitor indicates actually occurs? There shouldn't be too many gotchas, especially if you already had this working in a previous build.

Comment: Thank you for your Comment. The previous working method was an entry in the MoveFile table. this worked fine until i upgraded the TFS and Installshield. At the moment i'm working with an installscript which uses the "CopyFile" command. This is working as long as i set the installdir as the target directory. Now i added a second script which should copy the successfully saved file back to the right directory. but this doesn't work as well. The logfile of an installation just exposes one cryptical Error Message: "Note: 1: 2727 2: " But i didn't find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to try using MsiDiff, or a similar tool, to isolate what changed between the builds of your .msi packages. The error in the verbose log may be quite important.

> Note: 1: 2727 2:

If you look up [Windows Installer Error Messages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372835.aspx) and search for 2727, you'll find this error means

> The directory entry '[2]' does not exist in the Directory table.

Since `[2]` corresponds to the empty value in the message, this suggests that there is a table with a directory identifier that is incorrectly empty. You could try some of the usual suspects, such as running validation, to identify the problem. You mention the [MoveFile table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370055.aspx), but that takes properties instead of directories, so I'm uncertain if it would yield this message.

If this isn't enough to help you find the problem and resolve it, you should update your question with further specific details.

Comment: I Found a solution for that problem. The main issue was the command RenameFile(); This Command needs a Source and INSTALLDIR variable which is not set at the time where i want to execute the script. so i set the Path directly in the Parameters to avoid the ISTALLDIR Parameter. After this (monor) change the script worked as it should. Thank you for your help. Your hint with the Error Messages solved my problem! :)